# meteor return empty cursor from publication

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have some middleware in front of my publications:

```
 Meteor.publish(publicationIdentifier, function (...args) {
   try {
     middleware()
   } catch(error) {
     return Users.find('emptyCursor')
   }
   return Model.pubsub(...args)
 })
```

I need to return an empty Cursor when the middleware throws an error.
I currently do that by using find with an invalid id on some arbitrary collection:  `return Users.find('emptyCursor')`

Is there some better way to do this?

I have tried

```
return 
return false
return null
return new Mongo.Cursor()
```

Comment: I normally just do `this.ready()` without a return statement in such a branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in the [doc](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html)

```
    // Sometimes publish a query, sometimes publish nothing.
Meteor.publish('secretData', function () {
  if (this.userId === 'superuser') {
    return SecretData.find();
  } else {
    // Declare that no data is being published. If you leave this line out,
    // Meteor will never consider the subscription ready because it thinks
    // you're using the `added/changed/removed` interface where you have to
    // explicitly call `this.ready`.
    return [];
  }
});
```